Arduino Servo library servo.attach(pin) always inits at position 180 with 320 degree servo
I'm using the standard servo library with an Arduino Nano, using a a PDI-4409MG-320, a 320 degree low profile servo.  Very simply I want it to start at closed (5) and open (95) when the input pin is pulled low.  Yet, even if I do the write command before the attach, it will always go to 180 and stay there until I pull the input low, then it will go to open, and work normally after that.  The problem is that 180 is way out of the range and binds the servo to the mount.  I know I can modify the library, but I don't like to do this since I have to remember to do this every time I reinstall.  I've also tried adding delays, writing direct to the pin, and doing an initial close-open-close, all with the same result.  With another normal servo I tried works normally, but I need to use the low profile one because of space constraints.  Here is the code:
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo; 
int openpos = 95; //the open degrees
int closepos = 5; //closed degrees

void setup() {
  myservo.write(closepos); //pre-write closing before attach since attach moves servo on init
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(7)==0) { //if pin 7 is grounded, should open
    myservo.write(openpos);
    }
  else {
    myservo.write(closepos); //else close it
  }
delay(100);
}


The only way that I've been able to fix it is to do all three fixes, add a delay, write direct to the port, and perform an initial close-open-close.  This makes it twitch a couple degrees at power up, but that's much preferred to the 180 degree binding.  This is the fix:
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo; 
int openpos = 95; //the open degrees
int closepos = 5; //closed degrees
int first = 0; //check to see if it's first run

void setup() {
  delay(1500);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(9,1);
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  
}

void loop() {
  if (first==0) { //if first loop then prevent from going over
    myservo.write(closepos); //pre-write closing before attach since attach moves servo on init
    myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(openpos); //write open
    delay(100); 
    myservo.write(closepos); //write close
    first=1; 
  }

  if (digitalRead(7)==0) { //if pin 7 is grounded, should open
    myservo.write(openpos);
    }
  else {
    myservo.write(closepos); //else close it
  }
delay(100);
}


My question is, why does this happen only for this 320 degree servo, and is there a better fix for this?

you should refer to the datasheet of your servo and make sure that you're using the correct pulse widths.

The pulse widths are correct.  It's only the very first command that's interpreted wrong, all subsequent commands sent go to the correct position (and they're all the same two positions).  Again, this strange behavior of only the very first command going to 180 only happens with this 320 servo.  To reiterate: The first command, which should send it to 5 degrees, sends it all the way to 180 degrees, binding it.  It stays there until a command to go to 95 is given, which it goes to correctly, then after that will go correctly to 5 degrees, and work correctly.
